# PowerShell: -replace, regex and ($) dollar sign woes

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, dollar-sign

I am in the process of converting thousands of lines of batch code into PowerShell. I'm using regex to help with this process. The problem is part of the code is:

```
$`$2
```

When replaced it just shows `$2` and doesn't expand out the variable. I've also used single quotes for the second portion of replace instead of escaping the variables, same result.

```
$origString = @'
IF /I "%OPERATINGSYSTEM:~0,6%"=="WIN864" SET CACHE_OS=WIN864
...many more lines of batch code
'@

$replacedString = $origString -replace "(IF /I `"%)(.+)(:.+%`"==`")(.+`")(.+)","if ( $`$2 -match `"^`$4 ) {`$5 }"

$replacedString
```

Comment: Just for completeness sake whenever you post a string manipulation question, It would help everyone if you could give an example of the text before the manipulation (which you have) **and** what the string should look like after the manipulation.

Comment: Good idea. Will do next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$origString -replace "(IF /I `"%)(.+)(:.+%`"==`")(.+`")(.+)",'if ($$$2 -match "^$4" ) {$5 }'
```

Note the `$$$2`. This evaluates to `$` and content of `$2`.

---

Some code to show you the differences. Try it yourself:

```
'abc' -replace 'a(\w)', '$1'
'abc' -replace 'a(\w)', "$1"  # "$1" is expanded before replace to ''
'abc' -replace 'a(\w)', '$$$1'
'abc' -replace 'a(\w)', "$$$1" #variable $$ and $1 is expanded before regex replace
                               #$$ and $1 don't exist, so they are expanded to ''

$$ = 'xyz'
$1 = '123'
'abc' -replace 'a(\w)', "$$$1`$1" #"$$$1" is expanded to 'xyz123', but `$1 is used in regex
```

Comment: I was evaluating and trying to understand your examples and I don't understand why THIS: 'abc' -replace 'a(\w)', '$1' AND THIS: 'abc' -replace 'a(\w)', "$1" is different?

Comment: It's because `'$1'` and `"$1"` are (after you hit Enter or run the script) first parsed by PowerShell. The `'$1'` and `"$1"` are evaluated to strings according to some rules (see e.g. http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_quotes.htm and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx ). And after that the `-replace` operator is executed. It's how the interpreter works.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
 $replacedString = $origString -replace "(IF /I `"%)(.+)(:.+%`"==`")(.+`")(.+)","if ( $`$`$2 -match `"^`$4 ) {`$5 }"
```