# Having some trouble with Powershell -replace and Environment Variables from Batch File

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I finally narrowed down the problem, but need help understanding *why.*

Invoking Powershell from a batch file, the following works to replace a string within a file:

```
Powershell -Command "$foobar=[IO.File]::ReadAllText("$Env:File") ; 
$foobarred= $foobar -replace '(?<foo>.*Backup.).*.(?<bar>..Backup.)', '${foo}Enabled${bar}' ;
 [IO.File]::WriteAllText("$Env:File", $foobarred); "
```

Now if I try this, the command fails:

```
Powershell -Command "$foobar=[IO.File]::ReadAllText("$Env:File") ; 
$foobarred= $foobar -replace '(?<foo>.*$Env:StrStart.).*.(?<bar>..$Env:StrEnd.)', '${foo}$Env:StrVal${bar}' ;
 [IO.File]::WriteAllText("$Env:File", $foobarred); "
```

If I use a variable passed in from Batch, it fails everytime.  If I use PlainText in the command instead for the replacement value, it works just fine.  Why does this happen?

Comment: You're working with dynamically created regex here, and you're not regex-escaping any of your variables. You need to show the variable values you're using, ideally with a sample file, too. "It fails every time" is too little information to go on.

Comment: @Tomalak - the variables are produced in a GOTO loop.  There is always a pattern of an opening tag: `(.*SomeText.)` then the text I'm wanting to replace `.*.` then the Closing Tag: `(..SomeText.)`  I had the full scope of the script and batch file where this was all implemented, but it was incredibly wordy.  I'm not allowed to supply any of the information I'm working with from my work PC unfortunately.  The variables would be "StringStart" "StringVal" and "StringEnd" - "StringVal" will be the text I want to insert.

Comment: @Tomalak, would you like me to try and re-edit the question to include all of the previously included information so yo have full context?  I think the mod's in the S.O. Meta side are going to burn this question w/ number of edits

Comment: Looking at it again, I realized I goofed where I put the working version vs non.  The working version doesn't have any variables - only has ${foo} and ${bar} - the named Regex BackReferences.

The Strings inside the variables will not have any special characters, with the exception perhaps of the $StrVal. . .  In which case, I know I should probably use [regex]::escape($StrVal). . .  I think part of my problem is I'm also trying to use variables in my Pattern portion of the regex, but it's picking them up as the meta `$` - am I getting close?

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of how to apply [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279580/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-regular-expressions-in-powershell/13286724) and [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422669/quoting-replace-variables) in the -replace situation vs -match

Comment: Don't add the solution to problem to the question. Instead post it as an answer, if it solved your problem, you can also mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Ok - that makes sense - I will post it, but I think @Tomalak earned the Answer.  His answer was posted before I stumbled onto almost the same thing (string concatenation - similar to visual basic's method) - and his answer added the ps1 option - something which MANY other institutions may be looking for (mine just happens to be one where these are restricted. . .  If you're a mod who can stop the previous edit, that'll be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My observations would be

- you need to `[regex]::Escape()` arbitrary values when you build regular expressions dynamically.
- PowerShell does not do any string interpolation in single-quoted strings, so things like `'${foo}$Env:StrVal${bar}'` will not work the way you want.

I'd use the following command:

```
(Get-Content "filename" -Raw) -replace (
    '(.*' + [regex]::Escape("start string") + '.).*.(..' + [regex]::Escape("end string") + '.)'
),(
    '$1' + "replacement string" + '$2'
) | Set-Content "filename"
```

called ad-hoc from a batch file as follows (compressed onto one line):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "FILENAME=filename"
set "START=start string"
set "END=end string"
set "REPLACEMENT=replacement string"

set "PSCMD=(gc $Env:FILENAME -Raw) -replace ('(.*' + [regex]::Escape($Env:START) + '.).*.(..' + [regex]::Escape($Env:END) + '.)'),('$1' + $Env:REPLACEMENT + '$2') | sc $Env:FILENAME"

powershell -NoLogo -Command "&{%PSCMD%}"
```

But this is disproportionately hard to maintain.

I'd recommend writing a .ps1 file and passing named arguments, instead of juggling environment variables.

```
# MyReplace.ps1
param(
    [string]$Filename,
    [string]$Start,
    [string]$End,
    [string]$Replacement
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$content = Get-Content $Filename -Raw
$content = $content -replace ('(.*' + [regex]::Escape($Start) + '.).*.(..' + [regex]::Escape($End) + '.)'),('$1' + $Replacement + '$2')
$content | Set-Content $Filename
```

and in batch

```
powershell -NoLogo -File MyReplace.ps1 -Filename "filename" -Start "start string" -End "end string" -Replacement "replacement string"
```

That seems more manageable to me.

Comment: I finally found the solution, and it is very close to what you have posted here. 
 Unfortunately, we are forbidden from using PS1 scripts, so this is not an option.  Referring to your 1st  portion of the answer, this is very similar to what I found that finally worked: `Powershell -Command "$pattern= '(?<RangeStart>.*' + [regex]::Escape($Env:StrStart) + '.).*.(?<RangeEnd>..' + [regex]::Escape($Env:StrEnd) + '.)' ; $repl= '${RangeStart}' + $Env:StrVal + '${RangeEnd}' ; $fil2parse=(Get-Content $Env:FileTOParse) -replace $pattern, $repl | Set-Content $Env:FileTOParse; "`

Comment: @k1dfr0std Yes, your solution and mine are practically identical. While I don't understand the reasoning for restricting PS1 files, but allowing BAT files with arbitrary PowerShell code, I'm not going to argue it. :)

Comment: I KNOW RIGHT?!?  I don't get it either - it's not our choice. . . having to learn a bunch of arcane knowledge for Batch Programming is fun though

Comment: @k1dfr0std You would be surprised at the things people have come up with. I've written scraringly complex batch programs and all the time I find stuff that I did not know was possible.

Comment: Me too - Just this week, I learned about the ANSI/VT100 Escape sequences - w/ WIn10 we now have inline color, custom cursor placements, etc - and this was something which was available for AEONS on Linux systems.  Mind=Blown.

Comment: @k1dfr0std I've been using [ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) for that since... forever. :)

Comment: Ansicon?!?  Looking at the git just briefly (I'm not familiar enough yet w/ assembling something from git - I admit I have TON to learn) it appears it works for everything where Windows 10 wasn't!  So all this time - I could've had a lightweight executable do a ton of other work for me, when there was "no hope" before. . .  It feels like a neverending Christmas this week 

Answer (score 1):

At the advice of @Gerhard, adding what I found into the fray as an answer, but did ultimately giving @Tomalak the credit for the better answer overall.

In order to accept variables into both the match pattern and the replace pattern, you have to concatenate the strings (similar to how it is done in Visual Basic).

Reference below:

I have split the command up into multiple lines for readability - if you use this, place it on one line.

*Important - when using this, be sure to remove the line-breaks if you use it in a batch file.*  Also - be wary - I have had some circumstances where even using Set-Content can change the Encoding of the file.  I much prefer the secondary solution offered down below.

```
Powershell -Command "$pattern= '(?<RangeStart>.*' + [regex]::Escape($Env:StrStart) + '.).*.(?<RangeEnd>..' + [regex]::Escape($Env:StrEnd) + '.)' ;
$repl= '${RangeStart}' + $Env:StrVal + '${RangeEnd}' ;
$fil2parse=(Get-Content $Env:FileTOParse) -replace $pattern, $repl | Set-Content $Env:FileTOParse; "
```

This solution works as well, but I have had much fewer issues with it changing Encoding.

```
Powershell -Command "$pattern= '(?<RangeStart>.*' + [regex]::Escape($Env:StrStart) + '.).*.(?<RangeEnd>..' + [regex]::Escape($Env:StrEnd) + '.)' ;
$repl= '${RangeStart}' + $Env:StrVal + '${RangeEnd}' ;
$fil2parse=[IO.File]::ReadAllText("$Env:FileTOParse") ;
$filParsed= $fil2parse -replace $pattern, $repl ;
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("$Env:FileTOParse", $filParsed); "
```

Comment: `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` practically *need* to know the file encodings. If you don't specify them, that's always a bug waiting to happen, especially with files that are UTF-8 without BOM. Don't leave that to random chance, pin down the `-Encoding` parameter.