# Why does powershell remove one of the '$' when replacing?

Tags: regex, powershell

I've been scratching my head at this, and eventually ended up just using String.Replace, however, I'd like to know what Powershell is doing, can anyone explain it to me?

```
>"aaa" -replace "aaa", 'GG$$`~~'
```

results in:

```
GG$`~~
```

rather than

```
GG$$`~~
```

I was under the impression that single quotes prevented the expanding of stuff in the string, is this something to do with regex? If I put something between each dollar and backtick, it works, but that's not what I want...

Edit:

It seems that its a combination of things:

```
"aaa" -replace "aaa", '$$' --> "$"
"aaa" -replace "aaa", '$`' --> ""
```

I'm still none the wiser about why it's doing this though

Comment: You probably need to escape the `$` (note that `$` is a special character in regex).

Comment: Check also [This question: PowerShell: -replace, regex and ($) dollar sign woes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401713/powershell-replace-regex-and-dollar-sign-woes)

Comment: Looks like you're right, I just didn't expect to have to do it with the replacement string...

Comment: So it's only $$ that is the problem, `"aaa" -replace "aaa",'$#GG$$``~~' --> $#GG$``~~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a replace `$` indicates a backreference.

E.g. if you use:

```
"aaa" -replace "(aaa)", 'GG$1`~~'
GGaaa`~~
```

Using:

```
"aaa" -replace "(aaa)", 'GG$$1`~~'
GG$1`~~
```

So, really placing `$$` means you're placing a literal `$` character. If the variable doesn't exist...

```
"aaa" -replace "aaa", 'GG$`~~'
GG~~
```

The shell tries to find the variable `` $` `` but since it doesn't exist, you get an empty string for that.

So, to get

```
GG$$`~~
```

You have to use 4 $:

```
"aaa" -replace "(aaa)", 'GG$$$$`~~'
GG$$`~~
```

Each pair of `$$` meaning one literal `$`.

Using the same logic...

```
"aaa" -replace "aaa", '$$' --> "$"
"aaa" -replace "aaa", '$`' --> "" //Because the variable $` doesn't exist, it's 'null'.
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the key piece of info I was needing... 'back reference' :) Google wasn't too helpful trying to search for symbols.

Answer (score 0):

in normal regex a dollar sign ('$') indicates the end of the string...

In the above example you have your back ticks *after* the string with the $ sign, hence it wouldn't be escaping working on that string:
According to here: http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html

It should be: 'GG`$~~'

Comment: But I want the two $ signs and the backtick in the result, also it's not the pattern that it's matching, its the string that is the replacement that has the characters in it, why would that string be subject to the 'end of string' feature of regex?

Comment: I would guess it is because the replace can also include a regex (standard), so it just goes through the same processing as the search string